# Acomodar index de pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un *DataFrame* con el index así:

```
       rx
cpp       
0/0/12   1
0/0/13   1
0/0/6    1
0/1/0    3
0/1/1    1
0/1/10   1
0/1/12   2
0/1/13   9
0/1/14   9
0/1/15   2
0/1/2    1
0/1/5    2
0/1/6    3
0/1/9    5
```

Pandas me lo acomoda por el primer número del tercer número; lo que yo necesito es que quede así

```
       rx
cpp 
0/0/6    1      
0/0/12   1
0/0/13   1
0/1/0    3
0/1/1    1
0/1/2    1
0/1/5    2
0/1/6    3
0/1/9    5
0/1/10   1
0/1/12   2
0/1/13   9
0/1/14   9
0/1/15   2
```

No puedo acomodarlos de esa manera, me esta volviendo loco
Gracias!!

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para que los datos utilicen el formato adecuado. Agradezco que le des clic en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/448518/edit) y veas como se hace para una próxima ocasión. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que se me ha ocurrido es que el index sea de esta forma 00/01/12
entonces para eso primero hay que ver como convertirlo

```
'0/0/12'.split('/')
```

eso nos devolverá lo siguiente

```
['0','0','12']
```

ahora para hacer que el '0' sea un '00' o el '1' sea un '01' usamos f-string de la siguiente manera

```
'{:02d}'.format(0)
```

esto quiere decir que completaremos con el 0 hasta llegar a dos dígitos.
ahora para hacerlo en todo el arreglo usamos un bucle for (usando compresión de listas)

```
['{:02d}'.format(int(x)) for x in '0/0/12'.split('/')]
```

eso nos devolverá lo siguiente

```
['00','00','12']
```

y para convertir esa lista en una cadena de texto usamos join

```
'/'.join(['00','00','12'])
```

y esto devuelve

```
'00/00/12'
```

una vez comprendido esto hacemos una función que transforme los indices a este nuevo formato

```
def convert_string(index):
    return '/'.join(['{:02d}'.format(int(x)) for x in index.split('/')])
```

eso lo aplicamos al indice

```
index_col = df.index #obtenemos los índices
new_index = [convert_string(i) for i in index_col] #transformamos los índices usando la funcion que hemos creado
df.loc[:,'new_index'] = new_index #creamos una nueva columna, para no alterar el índice
df.sort_values(by = 'new_index',axis = 0) #ordenamos el datatraframe segun la nueva columna
```

con eso obtenemos la lista ordenada según lo que necesitas, ahora puedes acceder a los valores del dataframe según el índice

```
df.loc['0/0/12']['rx'] #esto devuelve 1
```

Espero te sirva :)